# Facebook login-button no longer appears after login then logout

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-authentication

My facebook login-button has been working great:

```
<fb:login-button length="long" background="light" perms="email"
                 size="medium" onlogin="myLoginCode()"></fb:login-button>
```

After a user logs in, that facebook login button disappears.  On my logout button I have something like this:

```
<a href="/security_logout" onclick="FB.logout();">logout</a>
```

When I click there, I'm logged out of both the facebook authentication mechanism and my own site.  So then I see the "Log in with Facebook" button again.

Problem is suddenly I noticed when you logout (and `FB.logout()` is called) the facebook login does **not** reappear!  You are kind of stuck then.  What changed?  If I call this from Firebug:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) alert(response.authResponse);
    else alert("not logged in");
});
```

I'll get an alert saying not logged in.  However, if I call `FB.login()`, I get this:

> FB.login() called when user is already connected

Any idea what's going on?  How do I get the Facebook login-button to reappear after someone has logged out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psychic debugging: `FB.logout()` makes an AJAX request, that method returns immediately when the request is made, so your browser navigates to your url `/security_logout` and drops the AJAX connection before the Facebook server has a chance to process it.

I guess you need to look at hooking into the logout response, wait for it to complete and only then navigate to `/security_logout`, something like this (untested, I just googled the API for `FB.logout()`):

```
<a href="#" onclick="my_fb_logout()">logout</a>
```

.

```
function my_fb_logout() {
    FB.logout(function (response) {
        // turn https://www.mywebsite.com/current_path?query_string=xyz#section1
        // into https://www.mywebsite.com
        var url_string = window.location.href;
        var base_url_len = url_string.length - window.location.pathname.length - window.location.search.length;
        var base_url = url_string.substr(0, base_url_len);

        // append /security_logout and redirect to your site's logout page
        var new_url = base_url + "/security_logout";
        window.location.href = new_url;
    });

    // this may not the best way to prevent bubbling of the event (navigating to # in the current page),
    // but will do fine in this case I believe 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you may be correct, the next page (the logout page) doesn't show the facebook login button.  However, the page after that does... I guess facebook needs a moment.  Strange though why my FB.getLoginStatus shows the user not logged in even before when the user was obviously logged in, the reason the login button wasn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to auth.logout with Javascript SDK http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
When the user log out from facebook, you can show the login button again.

Comment: Basically the user was not being logged out.  I was always trying to show the login button.

Comment: There is no attribute "onlogin" in < fb:login-button > documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/ My standart login button shows its status automatically. May be you should delete attribute onlogin, and place calling the function myLoginCode() to FB.login() ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="fb-btn"><div class='fb-login-button' data-scope='email,user_checkins,offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream'>Facebook</div></div>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '###########',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location="http://###########";
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        document.getElementById('fb-btn').innerHTML = "<a href='http://###########' class='fb_button fb_button_medium'><span class='fb_button_text'>Facebook</span></a>";
      }
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: care to add an explanation here?  blocks of text aren't a good way to teach anyone.